# What is the best approach to model relief models

Tags: modeling, sculpting, stl

I want to make models like [image]

I will be exporting them in STL format for carving. Is sculpting the best approach to this kind of model?

Comment: probably, if you can affort a high-poly mesh

Comment: One important part of the specification.. are undercuts permissible?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by undercuts

Comment: If I can't afford high-poly mesh?